# Apache 2.4 AliasMatch NotWorking

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf, regex, virtualhost

I used to Alias have as below for /CollabPortal14300  which was working fine

```
Alias /CollabPortal14300 D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/
Alias /datacert/api/entity/EmailDocument/\d+/DocumentVersion/1\.0 D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/core/html/blank.html

<Directory D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Require all denied
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|jpg|png|js|css|ico)$">
        Require all Granted
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
</Directory>
```

But we trying to eliminate the numbers from the Alias and trying to use RegEx instead. So I switched to AliasMatch as below

```
AliasMatch /CollabPortal\d{5} D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/
```

After switching to couldnt access the resources in `D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/`

Below are the access logs

```
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 403 246
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 403 248
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js HTTP/1.1" 403 262
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery-ui.js HTTP/1.1" 403 251
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery.treeview.js HTTP/1.1" 403 257
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery.treeview.async.js HTTP/1.1" 403 263
```

And in the error log I see

```
[Wed Nov 12 15:10:52.846478 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 42580:tid 916] [client fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c:61108] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
```

Can someone please help me why AliasMatch is not working?

Comment: Apache order directive issue?  Location instead of Directory?

Comment: What is Apache order directive issue? Using Location doesnt make sense since the resources am trying to access lives on file-system.

Comment: logging %f would show you what filesystem path it calculated

Answer (score 0):

You're not capturing anything, so you can't append the entire rest of the URL to the filesystem path in the 2nd argument. It's not implicitly captured and tacked on.